# Use the option IsolationLevel.ReadUncommited for only one query in DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

In a .NET Core Project I'm using EntityFramework and I have a DbContext (shopContext) injected in my class repository. I have the next query:

```
var res = shopContext.Orders.Where(x => x.Status == 1).Sum(p => p.Total);
```

Occasionally, the Orders table is doing maintenance tasks and the table is locked. For this query, I can't wait to the maintenance tasks and I need access to the table with the `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommited` option in the transaction:

```
using (var transaction = mutuaContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
{
    var res = shopContext.Orders.Where(x => x.Status == 1).Sum(p => p.Total);
}
```

The problem is that I only want that the context execute the query with this IsolationLevel configuration in these query, but the next queries continue executing although the table is locked yet.

Why are the following queries not waiting for the Table to be unlocked?

Example of my code:

```
using (var transaction = mutuaContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
{
    var res = shopContext.Orders.Where(x => x.Status == 1).Sum(p => p.Total); // this code would be executed
}

var total = shopContext.Orders.Where(x => x.Status == 0).Sum(p => p.Total); // this code would NOT be executed but is executed
```

I don't understand how the context get the transaction configuration. I would like that someone explain it to me.

I tried call to `transaction.Commit()` after fist query, but still not working.

Comment: Be extremely wary when using `READ UNCOMMITTED` on a query that reads like it's important that you get accurate results. `READ UNCOMMITTED` can skip or duplicate rows, which can cause something like a sum aggregate especially to come out wrong. You're better off looking into things like snapshot isolation and tightening up your maintenance windows rather than lowering your standards for consistency, if this is not a monitoring query whose results don't really matter because they'll be redone shortly.

Comment: Yes, I know the risk and the code in the question is code example. I need access with ```READ UNCOMMITED``` in the transaction or add in the sql query ```with(nolock)``` statment, but i have not found how to do it with Entity Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [raw SQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) (there is a similar `SqlQuery()` method for EF6, as well) and specify `with (nolock)` table hint. Something like this:

```
var res = shopContext.Orders.FromSqlRaw("select sum(Total) from dbo.Orders with (nolock) where Status = 1").ToList();
```

However, once you will deploy this into production environment and put your code under a decent concurrent load, most probably you will not like the outcome.

**UPD:** For EF Core 2.2, the syntax is a bit different:

```
var res = shopContext.Orders.FromSql("select * from Orders with(nolock)")
  .Where(x => x.Status == 1).Sum(p => p.Total);
```

Comment: It was my last option, to use a manual query, but i will have to use this if have not other way. I would like to use EF whenever possible. But `FromSqlRaw()` method is not in my Context. Why?

Comment: @Millas, it depends on which version of EF Core you are using. Both `FromSqlRaw()` and `FromSqlInterpolated()` did not exist in EF Core 2.2 and earlier. It's all described in the link mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I'm using EF Core 2.2 and the method name is `FromSql()`. But the correct use would be `shopContext.Orders.FromSql()`. I have been researching and I could to use: `var res = shopContext.Orders.FromSql("select * from Orders with(nolock)").Where(x => x.Status == 1).Sum(p => p.Total);` Do you see this correct?

Comment: I have never tried raw queries in EF myself, so probably you'll need to try and see if it works. I would setup a Profiler or XEvents session to see which query actually hits the database. Just to be sure, you know.

Comment: The Output window shows a query like: `SELECT SUM (a.Total) FROM (SELECT * FROM Orders WITH(NOLOCK)) AS a WHERE a.Status = 1`. I think this is correct. Is it same to `SELECT SUM(Total) FROM Orders WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE Status = 1`?

Comment: Yes, it works! Can I improve/complete your response and wilI I mark it as valid?

Comment: @Millas, updated, although you can add something else if you feel it necessary, of course.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
yourContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)
// your normal queries via yourContext  goes here
// do not forget to end the transaction
```

Comment: Sorry but did you read the question?